# Control Raspberry Pi with iPhone or Mac

Tags: java, python, swift, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I want to send my Pi a signal from an IOS Device or my MacBook. But I don't know how to do this. And what is the best way to do this? So some background information I got I Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+. So when you got any Ideas I need a sending program in Swift(for IOS or Mac), Python(for Mac) or a Java program(also for Mac). And I need a program for my Pi(preferably a Python application) to receive the signal. And at last sorry for my English, I'm from Germany and only in 8th grade. So, please use simple English. :)

Up front thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is just too broad - this site is dedicated to answering specific questions, and there are too many ways to do something like that. Look at a few tutorials first, and we'll gladly help you if you encounter any specific problems along the way of implementing this.

Comment: This sort of question is off topic for this site. You don't seem to have any code, you've mentioned 3 different languages... Are you actually trying to code something up or just want software recommendations that do it for you?

Comment: @Spelielekind005 why do you want to send the signal? To control GPIO? To run programs?

Comment: You can get started [here](https://www.imore.com/best-raspberry-pi-projects-iphone-users). Keep doing what you love young man!

Comment: A good place to ask questions specifically about the Raspberry Pi are the [Raspberry Pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using VNC viewer to connect to the Raspberry Pi and then giving it the command that you want it to execute. You will have to make sure that you enable the ssh option to connect to your Raspberry Pi and you'll also need the IP address of the pi along with the login credentials. This is what I'd do as your question seems to be a little too broad.